# Chronicle Permanode - Unable to add MQTT peer

Tags: node, permanode, iota-cli

I'm following the IOTA docs tutorial to run the permanode CLI tutorial, from [here](https://docs.iota.org/docs/chronicle/1.1/tutorials/run-a-permanode).

Step 1: Set up a Scylla node it's correctly done (using docker).

```
$ docker exec -it scylla nodetool status
Using /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml as the config file
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  965.02 KB  256          ?       222d1907-586d-46a4-9c8c-9ee9296f3b33  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  801.49 KB  256          ?       7f46da60-2714-47d8-a5a0-f9120f72fa4f  rack1
UN  172.17.0.4  964.67 KB  256          ?       55cc8c99-cbac-4eea-87c7-93dad14d90a1  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

*I've tried [this tutorial](https://www.scylladb.com/download/?platform=ubuntu-20.04&version=scylla-4.3) (Ubuntu 20.04 and Scylla 4.3) from Scylla too, but I'm still getting the same error. So I will illustrate my question with docker in case someone wants to reproduce it.*

Step 2: Download historial transactions is correctly done (not used to write this question).

Step 3: Install and configure Chronicle is correctly done (I guess, since I'm only trying to run the example of the documentation). You can check the `config.toml` file I'm using [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/chronicle.rs/blob/main/examples/permanode/config.toml).

Step 4: Run the permanode CLI. Here I'm using the following `cargo run` instruction:

```
$ cargo run --release --features "mainnet" --example permanode permanode/config.toml
```

And here is where I'm facing with the the problem:

```
$ cargo run --release --features "mainnet" --example permanode permanode/config.toml 
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.59s
     Running `target/release/examples/permanode permanode/config.toml`
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][permanode][INFO] Welcome to Chronicle Permanode Alpha v0.2.1
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::supervisor][INFO] Exposed stage reporters of shard: 0, to node: 172.17.0.2:9042 supervisor
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::supervisor][INFO] Exposed stage reporters of shard: 1, to node: 172.17.0.2:9042 supervisor
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::dashboard][INFO] Dashboard: AddNode: Ok(172.17.0.2:9042)
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::reporter][INFO] address: 172.17.0.2:9042, shard_id: 0, reporter_id: 0, received session: 1
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::reporter][INFO] address: 172.17.0.2:9042, shard_id: 0, reporter_id: 1, received session: 1
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::reporter][INFO] address: 172.17.0.2:9042, shard_id: 1, reporter_id: 1, received session: 1
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::stage::reporter][INFO] address: 172.17.0.2:9042, shard_id: 1, reporter_id: 0, received session: 1
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][chronicle_storage::dashboard][INFO] Dashboard: Built Ring: true
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][permanode][INFO] AppStatus: storage is Running, and got registered
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][permanode][INFO] AppStatus: api is Running, and got registered
[2021-02-23][19:35:44][permanode][INFO] AppStatus: broker is Running, and got registered    
[2021-02-23][19:35:49][chronicle_broker::broker::supervisor][ERROR] Unable to add MQTT peer 'topic: trytes, address: tcp://mqtt.iota.org:1883, id: 16796206012186321268'
[2021-02-23][19:35:50][chronicle_broker::broker::supervisor][ERROR] Unable to add MQTT peer 'topic: conf_trytes, address: tcp://mqtt.iota.org:1883, id: 8487946096541202025'
```

As you can see, the problem is in the last two lines:

```
[2021-02-23][19:35:49][chronicle_broker::broker::supervisor][ERROR] Unable to add MQTT peer 'topic: trytes, address: tcp://mqtt.iota.org:1883, id: 16796206012186321268'
[2021-02-23][19:35:50][chronicle_broker::broker::supervisor][ERROR] Unable to add MQTT peer 'topic: conf_trytes, address: tcp://mqtt.iota.org:1883, id: 8487946096541202025'
```

---

**Additional Information:**

- Chronicle Permanode Alpha v0.2.1
- OS and version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- No historial data files added

---

I've tried to run the tutorial in a clean VM (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) and in my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) without success. Also, I've been looking up on internet and I haven't found anything related with this error or a similar one.

I don't know if could be a problem with my network. Any ideas? Any help would be appreaciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't really have much experience in permanodes nowadays, but I would expect that you set up your own Hornet node first, and connect your permanode to its MQTT port instead of connecting it to some "random" IOTA node from mqtt.iota.org. Perhaps you want to try that route if nobody has a better idea.

Comment: Thank you very much @mihi. I will try with my own Hornet node, and if necessary I will update my question. Also, I couldn't find anything on internet about the `mqtt.iota.org` address, so I don't know if this address works or not.

Comment: As you said @mihi, I've set up my own Hornet node and now it works perfectly. If you want, consider writing an answer to this question and I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have much experience in permanodes nowadays, but I would expect that you set up your own Hornet node first, and connect your permanode to its MQTT port instead of connecting it to some "random" IOTA node from mqtt.iota.org. Perhaps you want to try that route if nobody has a better idea.